# Launching JConsole via WebStart

Tags: java, java-web-start, jconsole

I would like to know if it is possible to launch JConsole via web start.

For example, i have a web application and when the user clicks on a button (which has the IP:PORT of the JMX Endpoint) i would like to launch JConsole, so that the user will be able to monitor the specific JMX endpoint.

In my server i have Java installed, so i thought this would be possible.

Has anyone tried to do that before. Will i have any problems, considering i want to launch an application that was not developed by me?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT I**
The .jnlp file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">    
    <information>        
        <title>JConsole Web Start</title>        
        <vendor>User</vendor>    
    </information>        
    <security>         
        <all-permissions />    
    </security>        
    <resources>        
        <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="150m" max-heap-size="512m" />        
        <jar href="http://127.0.0.1/jconsole.jar" main="true" />    
    </resources>    
    <application-desc name="sun.tools.jconsole.JConsoleWebStart" 
main-class="sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole" width="300" height="300">        
        <argument><![CDATA[hostname:port]]></argument>    
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I found out that this can work. However, it is not working with Java 7, throwing an exception for **"Bad package name of main class"**. I tried Java 6 and is working normally, cannot really understand the reason.

**EDIT II:**
Finally i found that the reason the above .jnlp cannot start with Java 7 is the **sun.tools.jconsole** package name of the main class. It seems that Java7 does not like package names starting with sun. Thus, i created my own jar, which actually wraps the jconsole inside and it works.

Comment: The [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jconsole/info) says it's possible, but I've never tried it.

Comment: @trashgod  See tag edit for a new link on how to view the console.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Good edit, but now I wonder if this question is about [`JConsole`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JConsole); edited.

Comment: @trashgod  Interesting addition, for a confusing term. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson and trashgod. Thank you for the answer. Just to clarrify by JConsole i meant the MBeans monitoring tool. I tried quite many things and i think it is possible to launch JConsole via Web Start. However i was facing a problem when launching it by trying to launch using java sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole (which is supposed to be the main class). I am not sure if this is a java security problem (even if i specify all the permissions). You can have a look at this problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242547/jconsole-main-class

Comment: Only one person can be notified per comment.  I'll notify @trashgod

Comment: *"In my server i have Java installed"*  That is irrelevant.  The code is being run in a JRE on the ***user machine.***

Comment: By that i wanted to indicate that the server has the appropriate jconsole.jar file. Because i actually want to launch JConsole via WebStart. I have created the jnlp file which points to the location of the jconsole.jar in the server. But when trying to launch it i get an error of "Could not find or load main class sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole". In the beggining i thought this has to do with security manager but i added "<security> 
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>" in my .jnlp, still no luck. I have exracted jconsole.jar and i can see the manifest saying that main class is JConsole

Comment: I defer to @AndrewThompson's deeper understanding of how JWS uses the manifest, but you can examine the `Main-Class` and `Class-Path` attributes _in situ_ using [`Manifesto`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto). You might update your question to show both the `.jnlp` and the `.MF`.

Comment: @trashgod  Manifesto - nice!

Comment: @trashgod I have updated the question with the .jnlp file that i use. As i state in the edit, this .jnlp file works normally with Java 6, but not with Java 7. I could't figure the reason of this "Bad package name of main class" exception. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson just to notify you as well, i have updated the question with the .jnlp that i use. The .jnlp seems to be working with Java 6 (the JConsole launches successfuly), but not with Java 7. Could not understand the reason why. I have googled it and people say it is a bug in Java 7. However, i believe something else is the reason. I cannot believe that this is a bug.

Comment: @trashgod  [OT] I am hoping you can look over [Why should CS teachers stop teaching applets?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/why-should-cs-teachers-stop-teaching-applets/196500#196500).  I hoped to make a clearly reasoned argument, but feel my answer 'loses the plot' about half way through.  What think you?

Comment: can you please elaborate on how exactly you resolved the problem?
did you just pack the jConsole jar in your own signed jar?
in my case, I can't run a similar jConsole JNLP even with JDK 1.6u39