# JConsole Main class

Tags: java, jconsole

I am trying to start JConsole from the command line using its Main class.

I extracted the contents of jconsole.jar and in the MANIFEST.MF i can see

```
Main-Class: sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
```

So i am trying to run the following command:

```
java sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
```

But i am getting an exception of:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
```

Can anyone spot what am i missing here?

Comment: Why dont you run "jconsole" without java? It's an executable application

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch like this

```
java -jar jconsole.jar sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TheEwook . I know i can launch the jar via the above ways. The reason that i want to locate the main class and launch it, is because i intend to do it via Web Start (which needs a Main-Class). Thus i was trying to accomplish that first from the command line, but without any success.